# How to mass disable marketing cloud users?

Tags: marketing-cloud, user-management, marketingcloudapi

We have more than 100 users which we want to disable into the marketing cloud but doing them manually will take longer.

Is there any way possible to disable them in mass?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this help [How to mass deactivate users in Salesforce](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000A8fbiSAB) ?

Comment: @SubratSrivastava - your link relates to Sales Cloud, not Marketing Cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mass disable users in your regular UI. Just go into your Users menu item under Setup, and select the users you want to delete:

[image]

You will be prompted, to confirm the number of users to disable:

[image]

Once confirmed, you will find these users to have their status changed to *Disabled*

If you are dealing with a substantial number of users, and the above method is not sufficient, you can disable them by importing them in a CSV file. When viewing the Users list under Setup, you should click the Import icon, which will take you to this page:

[image]

Here you can see how you should format your data. You can even download a sample data file. Once you have your data ready, and all your records have Status set to Disabled, ensure the import is set to:

*Update existing users but do not add users that do not exist*

This will help you avoid creating new users, should your keys not match.

Comment: Lukas, I have users who are all different and might not be in the same list on the page. Is there any way of executing code where I can provide the list and can disable them in bulk?

Comment: @JimmyVaswani I have updated my answer with an additional method

Comment: @JimmyVaswani remember to mark my answer as accepted if it has been helpful